# How to change variable to next string in an array

Tags: javascript, typescript, date

Code:

```
months = [
    'January',
    'February',
    'March',
    'April',
    'May',
    'June',
    'July',
    'August',
    'September',
    'October',
    'November',
    'December'
  ];

currentMonth: String;

this.currentMonth = this.months[date.getMonth()];

nextMonth() {
    this.currentMonth = ...
}
```

How do I go about building the nextMonth function to change the value of currentMonth?  For example if its value is currently 'August', what should I add into my function to increment its value by 1, meaning, change its value to 'September'?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `indexOf` to look up `currentMonth` and increment:

```
nextMonth = months[(months.indexOf(currentMonth) + 1) % 12];
```

It is probably better to simply store the month number in `currentMonth`. Then you can simply increment currentMonth:

```
currentMonth = (currentMonth + 1) % 12;
```

and only reference the months array when you need the name:

```
currentMonthName = months[currentMonth];
```

Comment: Maybe it’s better to store `currentMonth` as a number to avoid this. Make a function to get the month name when you need it.

Comment: @BenWest agreed but that is not what OP asked for. Have edited the post to include that suggestion though as it is a good one.